# Setup Application Manager for nodejs in CPanel with AlmaLinux 8

Tags: node.js, centos, cpanel

I have uploaded my nodejs app in CPanel outside "public_html" and create application using "Application Manager". But only root path work fine.

For all other url path it show root file only.

For ex:
I have create an application on "http://example.com/test".

1. Open "http://example.com/test". output: "Hello world".
2. Open "http://example.com/test/page2". output: "Hello world".

How can I fix this?

I have run "npm start" to star server on terminal. and mapping with .htaccess file.

```
 RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/ [P,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^test/(.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L]
```

This method work fine. But I want to setup with "Application Manager".[image: "Application Manager" create app screenshot]